# Joining two tables and check if record exist

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying show some records from table and if doesn't exist to show button create new. If exist to show record.

There are two tables - `users`

```
user_id
username
...
```

And `restaurants`

```
rest_id
name
menu
```

So after user is created and he log into his account must have condition if `user_id` has restaurant `user_id = menu` (menu from restaurants). If doesn't exist in restaurant show button create. This is the query with which I trying

```
$q = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM restaurants m                 
          LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = m.menu WHERE rest_id = :user_id");

                $q->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
                $q->execute();
                // fetch the results
                $results = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if(count($results) > 0) {
                    foreach($results as $res) {
                        echo '<a href="users/restaurant.php?rest_id='. $res['rest_id'] .'"> '.$res['name'].' </a>';
                    }
                } else {
                        echo '<a href="users/restAdd.php?rest_id='.$_SESSION['user_id'].'">Create New</a>';
                }
```

In this way when user login he see button `Create New` because he doesn't have one. The problem is when he log again after he is created record already ... button `Create New` is visible again.

I thing the problem is in the query or no?

UPDATE:
`menu` row hold user_id from session when he create new one. This is in restAdd.php

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO restaurants ( name, menu, image) VALUE ( :name, :menu, :image)";
                    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $q->execute(array(
                ':name'     => $name,
                ':menu'     => $_SESSION['user_id'],
                ':image'    => $forDB
                ));
```

Comment: Check again your query, "users.user_id = m.menu" ??? Is this correct? If so, explain please

Comment: Well don't I need to check join user_id from `users` and menu from `restaurants`?

Comment: Pro tip: Don't use `SELECT *` especially in `JOIN` queries. Instead, enumerate the columns you need returned. Also, we can't tell from your question how exactly each row in your `restaurants` table relates to a row in your `users` table. Can you explain?

Comment: Row `menu` is FK of row `user_id` in users.

Comment: You want a relation 1user:Nrests, so you need a field in the table Restaurants pointing to table User. This field is what you need for that join, I doubt menu contains user id, what does contain menu field?

Comment: Remember to put some examples of the data contained

Comment: Field `menu` hold `user_id`. I've updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this query:

```
SELECT m.rest_id, m.name FROM restaurants m                 
  INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = m.menu
  WHERE menu = :user_id
```

1) INNER JOIN instead of LEFT, you want to check if there are restaurants related with the user.

2)I think you did a little mistake, the menu field is wich contains the user id

Comment: Thank's for your help. I guess I need to learn differences between LEFT, RIGHT, INNER and OUTER joins.

Comment: You're welcome. Here is one of my favourite answers of SO, check it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins

Answer (score -1):

In this case you need in your where clause `menu = :user_id` not `rest_id = :user_id`
Try with this:

```
SELECT * FROM restaurants m                 
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = m.menu WHERE menu = :user_id"
```